# Compound sorting in Parse using PHP -- subsort isn't working

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using this code:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("ParseClass");
$query->limit(10);
$query->ascending("updatedAt");
$query->addAscending("endDate");
$query->greaterThan('updatedAt', $last_updated_date);
$results = $query->find();
```

But the `$results` aren't sorted by "`endDate`." "`endDate`" is all over the place.

Any helpful ideas?

Thanks!

(Edit)

When I `print_r` the `ParseQuery` object, I see this:

```
Parse\ParseQuery Object
(
    [className:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => ParseClass
    [where:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
        (
            [updatedAt] => Array
                (
                    [$gt] => Array
                        (
                            [__type] => Date
                            [iso] => 2015-05-30T04:52:41.000Z
                        )

                )

        )

    [orderBy:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => updatedAt
            [1] => endDate
        )

    [includes:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [selectedKeys:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [skip:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => 0
    [count:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => 
    [limit:Parse\ParseQuery:private] => 10
)
```

Seems like it ought to work. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the sort in the end in case it was being overwritten by something, and I have put the other sort field into a csv in the ascending method call, see if it works:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("ParseClass");
$query->greaterThan('updatedAt', $last_updated_date);
$query->limit(10);
$query->ascending("updatedAt,endDate");
$results = $query->find();
```

Comment: Yeah, no dice -- still not subsorting by endDate. Weird.

Comment: Come to think of it, you want to sort on just date, or a period of time, say a week or month, for updateAt, then datetime for endDate. A subsort works when you have alot of equal values in the first sort.

Comment: Yup, that idea worked. Basically, querying a range of "updatedAt" values and then sorting them by "endDate." I still don't like that it didn't work as advertised on the box by Parse, but at least there's a workaround. Thanks!